# Angular 6 - Ionic - Break http request with interceptor and return json

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, observable, angular-http-interceptors

How to break httpRequest and return data (json in this case) using HttpInterceptor ?

Below the code I use for adding http header, I would like if debug is true, interrupt http request and return a JSON.

```
export class PostRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

//FakeResponse is a class which return JSON data passing type
fakeResponse:FakeResponse = new FakeResponse();

debug:boolean = false;

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if(this.debug){
        let jsonFakeResponse = this.fakeResponse.faker("ticket");
        // return the json jsonFakeResponse
    }else{
        const changedReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),withCredentials:true});
        return next.handle(changedReq);
    }

}
```

}

I know I should return an observable (ofc) but how to return it already resolved?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello @Andrea, I am facing the same issue. Have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if anyone need it. Since the Http request waits for a HttpResponseEvent, we have to create an object HttpResponseEvent and resolve it (with a promise).

```
export class PostRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

//FakeResponse is a class which return JSON data passing type
fakeResponse:FakeResponse = new FakeResponse();

debug:boolean = true;

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if(this.debug){



        //retrive jsonData from 
        let jsonDummyData = this.fakeResponse.select(req.body.params.Stmt);

        //Add header for content type
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type","application/json");

        return from(new Promise(resolve => 
            //wait 300 ms to simulate internet latency 
            setTimeout( () => {
                resolve(new HttpResponse({
                    body: jsonDummyData,
                    headers: headers
                }));
            },300) 
        ));

    }else{
        const changedReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),withCredentials:true});
        return next.handle(changedReq);
    }

 }

}
```

Removing next.handle statement will break the request.